# HttpWebRequest in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

I am trying to create `httpwebrequest` to one url (REST API) where i am writing stream to target api server. But before writing stream, in my request object : User Agent is throwing error that `'request.UserAgent'` threw an exception of type `'System.NotImplementedException'`. Even i have hard coded `useragent` value also. Same case with other two params `AllowAutoRedirect` and `CookieContainer`. On the other hand all other params having correct value or null.

Any help on this, why `UserAgent` param is throwing this error `'request.UserAgent'` threw an exception of type `'System.NotImplementedException'`. Below is my web request:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("TargetAPIIUrl_I am passing here"));

        request.Method = "POST";
        string boundary = "---------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        string formDataBoundary = "-----------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString().Substring(0, 14);
        string contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + formDataBoundary;
        request.ContentType = contentType;
        request.UserAgent = "Hardcoded string of my target API";
         request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(asyncResult =>
        {
            Stream stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asyncResult);

            SilverlightApplication1.TubeUtility.DataContractMultiPartSerializer ser = new         SilverlightApplication1.TubeUtility.DataContractMultiPartSerializer(boundary);
            ser.WriteObject(stream, parameters);
            stream.Close();
            request.BeginGetResponse(callback, request);
        }), request);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UserAgent` and `AllowAutoRedirect` properties are present to maintain some consistency with the .NET framework `HttpWebRequest`  however neither the ClientHTTP nor the BrowserHTTP implementations support them.

It is possible to use a `CookieContainer` with the ClientHTTP stack, the BrowserHTTP stack will of course use the host browser cookie management.